# Linq to convert bool[] to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, byte, bit

I have a list of boolean values within a array

```
bool[] items = { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,  //#1
                 false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true,  //#2
                 false, false, false, false, false, false, true , true  //#3
               };
```

Is there a easy way with linq to convert this into `byte[]`?

```
//expected result
byte[] result = { 255, 1, 3 };
```

Comment: My bad, though it's another *easy* question.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24087164/1997232) is *nearly* duplicated answer. Though you are converting *bits* represented as booleans, so an easier answer exists.

Comment: "Is there a easy way with linq to convert this" Easy is relative and subjective. I'd say no. Possible of course. Why so insistent on LINQ? You can probably build a house with salad tongs, but why? Use whatever makes your code the easiest to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a easy way with linq to convert this into `byte[]`?" I don't know if I'd call it easy, and it's certainly not pretty, but this seems to work:

```
        byte[] result = Enumerable.Range(0, items.Length / 8)
            .Select(i => (byte)items.Select(b => b ? 1 : 0)
                              .Skip(i * 8)
                              .Take(8)
                              .Aggregate((k, j) => 2 * k + j))
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a sequence of Booleans and you want to convert the values of every 8  consecutive Booleans into one Byte where the bit pattern equals the 8 Booleans with most significant bit (MSB) first.

[See how to convert an sequence of 8 Booleans into one byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322417/how-to-convert-bool-array-in-one-byte-and-later-convert-back-in-bool-array)

Converting is done in two steps:

- Divide your sequence into groups of 8 Booleans
- Convert every group of 8 Booleans into one Byte

To keep it readable I create extension functions of IEnumerable. See [Extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{

    public static IEnumerable<Byte> ToBytes(this IEnumerable<Bool> bools)
    {
        // converts the bools sequence into Bytes with the same 8 bit
        // pattern as 8 booleans in the array; MSB first
        if (bools == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bools));

        // while there are elements, take 8, and convert to Byte
        while (bools.Any())
        {
            IEnumerable<bool> eightBools = bools.Take(8);
            Byte convertedByte = eightBools.ToByte();
            yield return convertedByte();

             // remove the eight bools; do next iteration
             bools = bools.Skip(8);
        }
    }

    public static Byte ToByte(this IEnumerable<bool> bools)
    {    // converts the first 8 elements of the bools sequence
         // into one Byte with the same binary bit pattern
         // example: 00000011 = 3

         if (bools == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bools));
         var boolsToConvert = bools.Take(8);

         // convert
         byte result = 0;
         int index = 8 - source.Length;
         foreach (bool b in boolsToConvert)
         {
             if (b)
                 result |= (byte)(1 << (7 - index));
             index++;
         }
         return result;
    }
}
```

Usage will be as follows:

```
IEnumerable<bool> items = ...
IEnumerable<Byte> convertedItems = items.ToBytes();
```